# Is there another way to setComponentRestrictions to state instead of country?

Tags: google-maps

I want to know if I can set the google API to display Washington state only

I tried to use setComponentRestriction function but it only works for setting country only.

this is the code that I used:

```
inputName.setComponentRestrictions({'country': ['us']});
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using Google Places Autocomplete?
You can't restrict by state.

You can bias the autocomplete results to favor a location or area (bounds) and use the `strictBounds` option to restrict the results only to this given bounds.

```js
var washingtonStateBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(45.575378, -123.967677),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.006015, -116.790674));
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var options = {
  bounds: washingtonStateBounds,
  strictBounds: true,
  componentRestrictions: {
      'country': ['us']
  }
}
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

see a sample here:

https://jsfiddle.net/woosmap/895pq7nu/